# SELECT row with largest number of intersects

Tags: mysql, sql

For the following two tables

```
+-----------+-----------+
| recipe_id | some_data |
+-----------+-----------+
|         1 | etc       |
|         2 | etc       |
+-----------+-----------+
```

and

```
+----------------+-----------+
| ingredients_id | recipe_id |
+----------------+-----------+
|              1 |         1 |
|              1 |         2 |
|              2 |         1 |
|              2 |         3 |
+----------------+-----------+
```

Based on a set of ingredients, I would like to select the recipes with most matches.
e.g if I'll query for "milk, egg, salt" I'll get recipe_id 1 as the first result (because it had 2 matches) but If i'll search for "milk" retrieving 1 or 3 as the first answer would be equivalent.
My current effort can't find the "best" option, but only "all or nothing" by intersecting the different ingredients per recipe(ing_id_1_input is a user's input):

```
select r1.*
from (
select distinct ing1.recipe_id as recipe_id
from ingredients as ing1
where ing1.ing_id=ing_id_1_input) as prod_1 join
(select distinct ing2.recipe_id
from ingredients as ing2
where ing2.ing_id=ing_id_2_input) as prod_2
on prod_1.recipe_id=prod_2.recipe_id
join recipes as r1 on r1.recipe_id=prod_1.recipe_id
```

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function on a column, it works on the whole selected rows!!! Skip those brackets and simply do `select distinct ing1.recipe_id  as recipe_id ...` to write clearer code!

Comment: your example data confuses me.  Why do the same incredients have 2 entries?  Why is there a one-to-one relationship expressed between ingredients and recipes, given that we know ingredients will be used in several recipes?

Comment: I dropped the ing_name, maybe it was confusing, but the relationship is not one-to-one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do something like this:

```
select i.recipe_id
from ingredients i
where i.ingredient_name in ('milk', 'egg', 'salt')
group by i.recipe_id
order by count(*) desc;
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this works:

```
select r.*, (select count(*) 
               from ingredients as i1 where i1.recipe_id = r.recipe_id)
        - (select count(*) 
             from ingredients as i1 where ingredient_name in (input1,input2,input3) 
                                      and i1.recipe_id = r.recipe_id)
           as missing
 from recipe r
order by missing
```

input1, input2, input3 are the 3 available ingredients. This list can have variable length.

The last column contains the number of missing ingredients, 0 if all ingredients are available. So sorting on this column will put the smallest values on top.